# Multiple rowSelection listeners in p:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I need advise with selection listeners in p:dataTable. My view is primefaces extension layout 
(pe:layout), with north, left and center section. North section is table and left is a menu.

The idea is that left menu provides a different view for the data in selected table row
and therefore, if the row changes, the whole view need to refresh. (Depending on the view selected in left menu - these are backed by beans backigOne, two and three and only one at the time is active).

So I decided to use multiple rowSelect events for the table, for every bean:

```
 <p:dataTable id="" var="wo" value="#{TableBacking.dataList}"
    selection="#{TableBacking.selectedItem}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{wo}">

<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{backingOne.tableChangeListnener}" 
   update="..." disabled="#{leftMenuBacking.selection != "ONE" />
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{backingTwo.tableChangeListnener}" 
   update="..." disabled="#{leftMenuBacking.selection != "TWO"/>
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{backingThree.tableChangeListnener}" 
   update="..." disabled="#{leftMenuBacking.selection != "THREE" />

...

 </p:dataTable>
```

This works well and since always one item is selected in leftMenuBacking, only one ajax event will be enabled at the time.
**The problem is, however, all the backingOne, backingTwo and backingThree beans gets always initialized**, because of the declaration:

```
  listener="#{backingXXX.tableChangeListnener}"
```

and in my case, initialization is costly :( (timewise)

I need a hint of better desing, so the functionality is the same, but only the backing bean of the menu which is curently selected (or enabled as in sense of disabled="#{leftMenuBacking.selection != "ONE") gets initialized and no other does?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT 1** based on Magnus Tengdahl comment:

There are different pages for every selection in leftmenu.
The page backingOne.xhtml looks something like this:

```
   <ui:composition template="/publicResources/templates/gdfoxTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="title">GDFox | Similar Problems</ui:define>

<!-- North contains the section with table that produces rowSelect event as described above -->
<ui:define name="north">
      <ui:include src="currentWorkload.xhtml" />
</ui:define>

<!-- Contains the left munu, uses p:menu widget-->
<ui:define name="west">
        <ui:include src="leftmenu.xhtml" />
</ui:define>

<!-- center view  based on BackingOne bean-->
<ui:define name="center">
     ....
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
```

So basically, every selection on left menu is on different URL (let's just call them backinOne/Two/Three.xhtml. They share all share north and west sections and defines unique center

This is why needed to use three  for that table - in order to propage the change to all possible views (althought only one will be selected in time). I dont thing (== I am still failing to see) Magnus that one listenere would solve my problem. If you are sure your idea will work, could you please explain it little bit further?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with having just one `rowSelect` listener, without any `disabled` conditions:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{backingOne.tableChangeListnener}" 
    update="menuArea" />
```

Then let the backing bean decide what should be done given the selected row. Have a look at the [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf) for an example on how to get the selected row in the backing bean. From that information the backing bean surely must know what to do. Basically, you could just call the appropriate backing bean implementation in one of the backing beans.

You haven't given us any code for the left view, but I would recommend something like (if you don't do already):

```
<h:panelGroup id="menuArea">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{leftMenuBacking.selection == 'ONE'}">
        ... code for selection "ONE" ...
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{leftMenuBacking.selection == 'TWO'}">
        ... code for selection "TWO" ...
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{leftMenuBacking.selection == 'THREE'}">
        ... code for selection "THREE" ...
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

In this way, your left area will be re-rendered (i.e. updated) for every `rowSelect` and your selection table is left as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make an extra bean backingbean0. In that bean you have the listener tableChangeListener. As Magnus stated you have 1 p:ajax
And in the tableChangeListener you can call backingbean1 2 or 3 depending on the one that is needed. (you have this info in your backingbean0)

```
protected Object getBean(String name) {
    FacesContext fcontext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELResolver resolver = fcontext.getApplication().getELResolver();
    Object bean = resolver.getValue(fcontext.getELContext(), null, name);

    if (bean == null) {
        getLog().warn("An object with name=" + name + " could not be resolved with ELResolver");
    }

    return bean;
}
```

and you call it like this

```
BackingBean1 bb1 = (BackingBean1) getBean("bb1");
```